# Simple Audio Unit crashes AU Lab, looking for HasCustomView?

Tags: audio, osx-mavericks, core-audio

I'm trying to make a simple Audio Unit for the first time and the lack of updated documentation about basic things like simply creating a unit is very frustrating.

I did not want to just copy TremoloUnit and tweak it, I want to learn how to make one from scratch. So I set a very simple audio unit, not doing anything, just to be recognized and opened, thats all. I set everything up (bundle settings, plist etc) like the TremoloUnit Apple has as an example, but now AULab crashes when it tries to open my unit with this:

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: HasCustomView)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called

Obviously, it is searching for a key it can't find in some dictionary. I was not able to find any info on either what that dictionary should be named, where should it be defined, what should the default location for it be (static within the plist? Within the AudioComponents array? Dynamic via a callback?) and I'm basically stumped. All of my code seems to copy exactly what TremoloUnit does, but obviously I'm missing something. FTR, TremoloUnit does not define this property anywhere either, so this must be some 'magic' that Apple expects somewhere along the way.

If you can help out, I'll be very thankful.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by a mispelled factoryFunction entry in the plist for the plugin. A letter was upper case as opposed to lower. If anyone runs into a similar problem, check the plist entry and make sure it is spelled correctly.